Why can I see the shell variable with argv?
So, I was testing something with argc and argv in C language, and i discovered this.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(%s\n", argv[2]);
}

I compile it and rum this from my terminal like this ./a.out, and the result is SHELL=/bin/bash, my shell variable...
I use foot, the default terminal of sway.
I just want to know why. First time here by the way :)

What's next in memory is undefined. In your case it happens to be the environment, but any code you wrote making the assumption would be inherently nonportable. (Moreover, Stack Overflow's scope is limited to "practical, answerable" questions, and depending on undefined behavior is inherently impractical, so I'm tempted to argue that the question is inherently off-topic; the safe way to access the environment is via documented interfaces such as the environ pointer or the envp argument to main, or functions like getenv() and setenv() that use those interfaces).

(the reason you get the SHELL variable in particular is presumably that it's the first variable within the structure; this is another example of undefined behavior -- it just happens by coincidence to be the one that's first).

You're not allowed to access any elements of argv that aren't at non-negative indices less than argc.  If you do, you get undefined behavior which can be interesting but is never useful and can't be relied upon.  :)

Some compilers allow int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) but this is not allowed by the C Standard or POSIX. See, eg, https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html

@JeremyFriesner: Re “undefined behavior which can be interesting but is never useful and can't be relied upon”: That is not what the C standard means by undefined behavior. Linking to operating system routines, e.g., for using networking services, is undefined behavior as specified by the C standard but is useful and can be relied upon. In the C standard, undefined behavior does not mean you may not do it; it means it is not covered by the C standard, and it could be used as an extension to the language.

@pmg: The C standard allows it in C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1: “… It [main] shall be defined… or in some other implementation-defined manner.”

Why? Because you were unlucky! Had you been lucky, you'd have gotten a segfault :-)

@JeremyFriesner argv[argc] is NULL, a sentinel in addition to the length provided. But in OP's case, without arguments using argv[2] is undefined behaviour.

@WeatherVane yes, I had forgotten about the NULL entry.  It's still not good a good idea to read that one, though :)

See What should main() return in C and C++?  Some of the answers discuss alternative forms for invoking the main() function, and what you are seeing is a consequence of undefined behaviour (accessing the argv array beyond the end of the array) — but it accidentally looks at the the envp environment array because of the way the memory is laid out.
